# Using Title as URL param on a blog post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a small CRUD blog-like webpage using Mongoose and express

Right now, the routing of each post use the ID on the URL like this:

```
singlePost.get = () => {

  Blog.findById(req.params.id, (err, blogs) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } else {

      res.render('single_post', {
        blogs: blogs
      })
    }
  })
}
```

a just link the blog + the Id and that's it. www.mypage.com/blog/id works as intended.

But I want to have the title of the post instead of the Id. So I add a "title2"  parameter on the document I store on the DB. Title2 is just the Title after I modified a little to change from "title of the post" to "title_of_the_post".

it worked, and I can use the title2 param on the view for all my posts.

To use the title2 as url param, I tried this:

```
singlePost.get = (req, res) => {

  Blog.find({title2: req.params.title2}, (err, blogs) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } else {
      console.log(blogs);
      res.render('single_post', {
        blogs:blogs
      })
    }
  })
}
```

the console.log actually returns the object:

```
[ { _id: idNumber,
    title2: 'esto_debiera_ser_el_titulo_2',
    body: '<p>jojoji sjsjjdh</p>',
    title: 'esto debiera ser el titulo 2',
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2017-07-22T15:56:03.575Z } ]
```

But on the view now I cant access the values doing the same as before. I'm working with handlebars so is just {{blogs.title}} and so on.

If the element I need is being returned, why can't I use it on the view exactly as I was before?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a side note not related to your actual problem: what you called `title2` is often referred to as `slug`. There are libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findById` returns a single object, `find` returns an array. Use `findOne` to get the desired result.